# why my program is giving garbage value in o/p after providing sufficient inputs? code is as follows:

Tags: c

Why my program is giving garbage value in O/P after providing sufficient     inputs?

I have given I/P as `10 & 40` & choose multiplication option as `3`.

My code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,x;
    printf("Enter a & b \n");    //printing
    scanf("%d %d, &a,&b");
    printf("1. add \n 2. sub \n 3. multiply \n 4. div \n 5. mod \n 6. and \n 7. or\n 8. not \n 9. xor \n");
    printf("Enter your choice \n");
    scanf("%d, &x");

    switch(x)
    {
        case 1: c=a+b;
                break;

        case 2: c=a-b;
                break;

        case 3: c=a*b;
                break;

        case 4: c=a/b;
                break;

        case 5: c=a%b;
                break;

        case 6: c=a && b;
                break;

        case 7: c=a || b;
                break;        

        case 8: c=~a;
                break;

        case 9: c=a^b;
                break;

        default: printf("Make correct choice\n");
    }

    printf("result is: %d",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %d, &a,&b");`? Check those quotes!

Comment: Always check the return value of scanf

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to scanf function in line number 5 & 8 and no buckets to hold the scanned/read arguments.

The `scanf` function's prototype is as follows:

`int scanf(const char *format_string, ...);`

Where the `format_string` is string containing `format specifiers` such as `%d, %f`...etc

And `"..."` in prototype means variable number of arguments. The arguments are buckets to hold the values that `scanf` fills by reading the `format_string`.

Hence the corrected lines of code should be

```
line 5.  scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
line 8.  scanf("%d", &x);
```

Another notewothy thing is the variable arguments for `scanf` are always pointers to objects.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of scanf function is

```
scanf(“format string”, argument list);
```

So for example, change

```
scanf("%d %d, &a,&b");
scanf("%d, &x");
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d", &a,&b);
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your input nothing to be scan from your console or any other input.

please check scanf() sysntax.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a,b,c,x;
 printf("Enter a & b \n"); //printing 
 scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
 printf("1. add \n 2. sub \n 3. multiply \n 4. div \n 5. mod \n 6. and \n 7. or\n 8. not \n 9. xor \n");
 printf("Enter your choice \n");
 scanf("%d", &x);
 switch(x)
 {
  case 1:   c=a+b;

    break;
 case 2:  c=a-b;

    break;
 case 3:  c=a*b;

    break;
case 4:  c=a/b;

    break;
case 5:  c=a%b;

     break;
case 6:  c=a && b;

     break;
case 7:  c=a || b;

      break;
case 8:  c=~a;

    break;
case 9:  c=a^b;

     break;
default: printf("Make correct choice\n");
}
  printf("result is: %d",c);
  return 0;
 }
```